# Is 你好，北京 grammatical?

Tags: translation, expressions, greetings

Today Victoria Beckham [tweeted](https://twitter.com/victoriabeckham/status/577387418359324672) it. But is this reverse form (as opposed to 北京，你好) correct?

Comment: Instead of simply throwing out the question, what do you think and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct!!
你好，北京 is more like a casual greeting, e.g. Hello World! :D
北京，你好 is more like a greeting with a touch of respect, because you address the name first. Examples are, 张老师，你好 (Teacher Zhang, hello).

Comment: Thanks, I have the impression, that the 你好，X form sounds more like a machine translation of it's English equivalent.

Comment: No no. 你好, xxx is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

"你好，北京" is usually said by one come to Beijing the first time becaurse Beijing is a new friend to him. However, "北京，你好" is usually used by one has lived in Beijing for many years and he treats Beijing as his old friend.